# Error when attempting to set custom animation for the viewController transition iOS4

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I am building an iPhone app and I have implemented a section for knowledge base about the app's subject matter. I used a table view and navigation viewController so that upon selecting any cell in the table a new view controller will be created and added on to the navigation stack.

I tried to implement the curl up/ down animation myself but i get this error at runtime

> Parent view controller is using legacy containment in call to
>   -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'

here is the code sample

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// change the accessory button to activity indicator
UITableViewCell *cell = [mTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


SomeViewController *ad = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ad.title = cell.textLabel.text;


[self.navigationController addChildViewController:ad];
[self.navigationController transitionFromViewController:self toViewController:ad duration:0.7 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL completed){
    [ad release];
}];
```

Any help, advice and tips is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey I got the same exception when my custom containment view controller was a subclass of UINavigationViewController. When I made my containment vc a subclass of UIViewController it worked like a charm.
Your problem might be different. From the apple docs:

> This method is only intended to be called by an implementation of a
>   custom container view controller. If you override this method, you
>   must call super in your implementation.

You are calling this method on a UINavigationViewController instance, not on an instance of a custom container view controller.